# How to store value of a variable in c after closing

Tags: c, variables, scope, global, local

I am doing a project on railway reservation system, my program is working fine, but when I close the program and then again start booking tickets,seat no again takes the previous value, I'm doing the project in c.

Comment: You'll need to write all of the data to a file before the program closes, and then read the data from the file when the program starts again.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write all of the data to a file before the program closes, and then read the data from the file when the program starts again.

That's right.